# Maven in eclipse Indigo, project dependency on Runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-indigo

I have a maven project in Eclipse which has as a dependency another project which I've installed in my local repo with `mvn clean install`. The dependency in pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mydependency</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run the project from eclipse in tomcat, *Run On Server*, it runs fine If I don't have the other project loaded in eclipse(*mydependency*). If I import *mydependency* as a maven project in eclipse(I need to for debugging purposes), the project fails on runtime with `ClassNotFoundException`. It cannot find classes of *mydependency* project. 
What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I've tried the usual, clean, delete, reimport projects, switch workspaces, delete/recreate tomcat in eclipse, even switched eclipse installation...

Comment: What did you do apart from import mydependency project in Eclipse? simply import one project should not affect existing project build configuration, unless you explicitly alter something on existing project.

Comment: Are you using m2e?  If so, have you run `Update Project Configuration...`?

Comment: No I don't remember altering, what alters in which files would describe the scenario? Yes I'm using m2e and Update Project Configuration doesn't solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: I don't get much details from the info you posted, so only make a comments. The normal way we do (enable source debug in dependent project) is add the dependent project into main project' build path. Right-click -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path, in Projects tab, add library project here, then in Order and Export tab, alter the order of the list, move dependent project up to above maven library dependency. try it out and see if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First solution:**
Choose on your project `right-click-> Maven -> Disable workspace resolution`

Now when you will debug the debugger will find the jar file - not the source. You has to attach source code to the library (choose java project)

**Second solution**

Run your project on tomcat as war file and debug remotely.

**Third solution**

Install [JD-Eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse) . It is helpful, but sometimes the lines of code are not the same as decompiled.

Comment: Thank you Ajozwik, the first solution seems to come handy and I can debug, but I'd like to know the cause, hence I'll not accept the answer for a little more to see if someone comes with another answer.

Comment: You welcome. I think eclipse classloader loads class from project, when tomcat tried to load from WEB-INF/lib. Read about tomcat classloaders.